# Having trouble setting a range a numbers that a user can input

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I am writing a program and have everything working fine except the function below. I am curious as to what would work best to make it so that the users inputs for the first loop can only be from 1 - 69, and the second loop from 1 - 26.

I was going to do a do/while loop but got an error as mentioned below.

```
//***********************************************
//Case 4 lets you input your own lottery numbers*
//***********************************************
void case4()
{
    cout << numberprint << endl;
    tickettop();
    int array_pick[4];
    int pballp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        cout << evalue << i + 1 << space1;
        do 
       {
        cin >> array_pick[i];
        } while (array_pick > 0 && array_pick <= 69); //Here is where I get an error for array_pick <= 69 (operand types are incompatible ( int * and int))
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        cout << eball;
        cin >> pballp;
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
    ofs << endl;
    ticketbottom();
    ofs << bar << box << bar << endl;
}
```

Comment: `while (!(array_pick > 0 && array_pick <= 69));`, I don't see your second attempt.

Answer (score 1):

```
int lottonumber;

ask: //goto label
cin >> lottonumber; //prompt value in console
//if lower than 1 or higher than 69, goto label
if (lottonumber < 1 || lottonumber > 69)goto ask;
```

People dislike the `goto` label, but in this case its not a problem. While loops and for loops are there to make the code more understandable and organizable. The goto label wont make your program slow or 'bad', it will just make it harder to organize. Or in this case, easier.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a number of issues. There are 2 issues with this line:

```
} while (array_pick > 0 && array_pick <= 69);
```

Firstly, you are comparing an array to an integer, that's where the compiler error comes from. Secondly, the condition should be the opposite to what it is now: you want the loop to continue until the user enters a correct value, therefore you need the condition to be true if the entered value is out of range, not when it's actually correct.

What you probably mean to do is this:

```
} while (array_pick[i] < 0 || array_pick[i] > 69);
```

To check the second input you can use the same `do...while` construct, just change the condition:

```
cout << eball;
do 
{
    cin >> pballp;
} while (pballp < 0 || pballp > 26);
```

But there are other problems with your code, even though the rest of it is *syntactically* correct, as far as I can tell.

The first loop will go out of bounds of your `array_pick` array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

`i` will take values 0, 1, 2, 3 **and 4**, but the array you're modifying in this loop is defined as `int array_pick[4]`, so there will only be elements with indexes 0, 1, 2 and 3.

The second `for` is pointless, as the loop will only ever do a single iteration.